# jquery Instafeed if functon exist or condtion exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Instagram  jquery script. 
A simple Instagram javascript plugin http://instafeedjs.com
Iam use ing instafeed code: site

basic use instrgram condions

https://github.com/johndeng/instafeed.js

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($){
        var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'user',
            target : "instagram-feeds,
            limit : 3,
            userId: userid,
            accessToken : accesstoken
        });
        feed.run();
});
```

Problem with instafeed for instagram is function exist.
i will try if condtion  condtion error showing.

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($){
    if ( $.isFunction($.fn.Instafeed ) ) {
        var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'user',
            target : "instagram-feeds,
            limit : 3,
            userId: userid,
            accessToken : accesstoken
        });
        feed.run();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the **Instafeed** is function, you have to check it on global window object, rather than jQuery:

```
if(typeof(window.Instafeed) === "function") {
   // Instafeed is a function
}
```